# Remove Customizer Control Choices (Type: Radio Array) using Child Themes

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

Is there a way to remove one of the choices from radio array? For example, I'm trying to remove 'bottom' from the choices' array:

```
    $wp_customize->add_control(
    'your_control_id', 
    array(
        'label'    => __( 'Control Label', 'mytheme' ),
        'section'  => 'your_section_id',
        'description' => 'your_description,
        'settings' => 'your_setting_id',
        'type'     => 'radio',
        'choices'  => array(
            'top'  => 'top',
            'bottom'  => 'bottom',
            'left'  => 'left',
            'right' => 'right',
        ),
    )
);
```

I know that the class below can modify nearly all the values from the control except the choices' array:

```
$wp_customize->get_control('your_control_id')->description = __( 'New Description' );
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a `new array` there, with the updated options:

```
$wp_customize->get_control( 'your_control_id' )->choices = array( 'top' => 'top', 'bottom' => 'bottom' );
```

[image]

used this in my `functions.php`

```
function modify_choice( $wp_customize ){
    $wp_customize->get_control( 'your_control_id' )->choices = array( 'top' => 'top', 'bottom' => 'bottom' );
}

add_action( 'customize_register' , 'modify_choice',999 );
```